# Find the minimum length

Tags: geometry, algebra-precalculus, derivatives

Given rectangle $ABCD$ where $AB=CD=4$ and $AC=BD=2$. Point $E$ is in middle of $AC$. Point $X$ is somewhere in the line $AB$. Find polygonal chain $EXC$ of minimum length.

How do you find minimum length? If we use $x$ and $4-x$ as variables then we can use pythagorean theorem: $f(x) =\sqrt{x^2 + 1} + \sqrt{(4-x)^2+4}$.

Is my approach fundamentally wrong or how do you find the $f'(x) =0$?

Comment: In your rectangle $ABCD$, one side is longer than the diagonal??

Comment: (Barring the nonsensical dimensions, it seems like you meant $ABDC$ to be a $ 2 \times 4$ rectangle.) Your approach would work. What have you tried to find $f'(x)$? Or solving $f'(x) = 0$? $\quad$ For another approach, hint: Try converting $EX+XC$ into the distance between 2 points, and use the fact that the shortest distance between 2 points is a straight line.

Comment: Please see [this article on MathSE protocol](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33190/how-to-avoid-downvotes-for-beginners-questions/33236#33236).
As onerous as the article may appear to you, it provides a defense mechanism against the MathSE forum being used as a *do my homework* forum.  In particular, please see the **Edit-Tools** section of the article, and the portion of the article that discusses *showing work*.  It is **irrelevant** whether the problem is homework.  What counts is whether the protocol is observed.

Comment: If your intent is that the rectangle is a $~4 \times 2~$ rectangle, then the distance function should be $$f(x) = \sqrt{x^2 + 1} + \sqrt{ ~(2 - x)^2 + 4}.$$

Answer (score 1):

The equation you are after is
$$f_x: y = \sqrt{x^2+1}+\sqrt{x^2+4}$$

It is immediately obvious that $f_x$ has its extremum at $x=0$ in point $(0,3)$ which stands for a minimal distance of $3$, achieved by chosing $X$ to lie at $x=0$, which is point $A$.

The graph of $f_x$ is shown in green. The length of the polygonal chain $EXC$ is given by equating $f(X_x)$.

[image]